# Spring MVC Thymeleaf Error when attempting to hook a form into controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Fighting the good fight with Spring / Thymeleaf having decided to try and turn a console app into a web app.

I have a form with 3 different buttons, each one is going to a different method in the controller.  I'm then intending on having the methods each do their own thing and return the results as needed but currently getting an error with respect to the params.

Looking online, it appears as though I'm following an example given but no joy, any help greatly appreciated.

The exception:

```
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Mar 02 17:08:48 GMT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Parameter conditions "action=tb_name" not met for actual request parameters: tb_name={tb_name}
```

The Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/sparql", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=tb_age")
    public String tb_age(Model model){
        String queryString = "tb_age query";
        String queryResult = "tb_age result";

        model.addAttribute("sparqlQuery", queryString);
        model.addAttribute("sparqlAnswer", queryResult);
        model.addAttribute("now", dateTime);

        return "sparqlanswer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/sparql", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=dc_age")
    public String dc_age(Model model){
        String queryString = "dc_age query";
        String queryResult = "dc_age result";

        model.addAttribute("sparqlQuery", queryString);
        model.addAttribute("sparqlAnswer", queryResult);
        model.addAttribute("now", dateTime);
        return "sparqlanswer";
    }
```

The form html page:

```
   <p>
        <form action="#" data-th-action="@{/sparql/question}" data-th-object="${model}" method="post">
            <p>How old is tb</p><button type="submit" name="action" value="tb_age">Ask?</button>
            <p>How old is dc</p><button type="submit" name="action" value="dc_age">Ask?</button>
            <p>What is the birth name of tb?</p><button type="submit" name="tb_name" value="tb_name">Ask?</button>
        </form>
    </p>
```

The results html page that I'm forwarding to:

```
  <p>Results:</p>
    <p>Question asked: </p>
    <p>Sparql Query: <strong th:text="${sparqlQuery}"></strong></p>
    <p>Answer: <strong th:text="${sparqlAnswer}"></strong></p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sparql/question", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "tb_age")public String tb_age(Model model) {
return "sparqlanswer   tb_age";}

@RequestMapping(value = "/sparql/question", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "dc_age")
public String dc_age(Model modeld) {
    return "sparqlanswer  dc_age";}

@RequestMapping(value = "/sparql/question", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "tb_name")public String tb_name(Model model) {
return "sparqlanswer  tb_name";}
```

Comment: <form action="#" data-th-action="@{/sparql/question}" data-th-object="${model}" method="post">
<button type="submit" formaction="/sparql/question?tb_age" >Ask?</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="/sparql/question?dc_age" >Ask?</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="/sparql/question?tb_name" >Ask?</button>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

You are using params value incorrectly. Params is a list of parameters names only not a list of name =values. Also there is a formaction attribute you can add to your button to post to a specific url.